# How do i validate forms with semantic-ui-react

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm using the official [Semantic UI React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/) components to create a web application. I have a [form](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form) on a search page, which contains an [input](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/input) field.

```
import React from 'react'
import {Form} from "semantic-ui-react";
import RadiusOfSearchInput from "./RadiusOfSearchInput";

const NearbyShopsSearchForm = (props) => {
  const { onSubmit, size, action, onChange, value, style } = props

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <RadiusOfSearchInput size={size}
                           action={action}
                           onChange={onChange}
                           value={value}
                           style={style} />
    </Form>
  )
} 

export default NearbyShopsSearchForm
```

The component that uses the form is as shown below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Menu, Container, Segment} from 'semantic-ui-react'
import ShopCardList from "../components/ShopCardList";
import axios from 'axios';
import NearbyShopsSearchForm from "../components/NearbyShopsSearchForm";

class NearbyShopsPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      radius: '',
      shops: []
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange = (e, { value } ) => {
    this.setState({ radius: value })
  }

  handleSubmit = (e, data) => {
    const { radius } = this.state
    const url = `/api/shops/@33.846978,-6.775816,${radius}`

    axios.get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ shops: response.data })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })

    e.preventDefault()
  }

  render() {
    const { radius } = this.state

    return (
      <Segment basic>
        <Menu fixed='top' size='huge' borderless>
          <Menu.Item>
            <NearbyShopsSearchForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                                   size='large'
                                   action={{ color: 'teal', content: 'Search', size: 'small' }}
                                   onChange={this.handleChange}
                                   value={radius}
                                   style={{ width: '17.5em' }} />
          </Menu.Item>
        </Menu>

        <Container style={{ marginTop: '5.5em' }}>
          <ShopCardList shops={this.state.shops}/>
        </Container>
      </Segment>
    )
  }
}

export default NearbyShopsPage
```

I want to validate the form so it won't submit values other than decimals, which are valid values to represent a distance. I didn't find validation support in the SUIR official documentation. I'm aware of the redux-form possibility, but i fail to implement it correctly. what's the recommended and simplest way to implement the data validation feature?

Comment: A simple `if (dataIsNotValid) return;` will do it... also you should call `preventDefault()` at the start of your method

Comment: @SrThompson Would you please explain why i should put `preventDefault()` at the start of `handleSubmit`?

Comment: @AnouarBellakha By default, a form submit will refresh the page. Adding `e.preventDefault()` will override that default behaviour.

Comment: What @ChaseDeAnda said is correct. That would reset your component's state and you'd lose the user's input